# What's the significance of the title 'Śrīla (श्रील)' generally used by Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇavas?

Tags: krishna, history, name, gaudiya-vaishnavism

One may generally observe, that almost all the ācāryas from the Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇava lineage (especially the ISCKON) use this term - "Śrīla", as a title, for their ācāryas, and even for Maharṣi Veda Vyāsa (Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana).

For instance:

> - Śrīla Veda Vyāsa, [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/ssr/2/)
> - Śrīla Śukadeva Gosvāmī, [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/1/4/)
> - Śrīla Śrīdhara Svāmī, [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/2/40/)
> - Śrīla Jīva Gosvāmī, [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/1/1/)
> - Śrīla Prabhupāda, [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/spl/)

#### So, what's exactly the origin, meaning, and significance of this word - 'Śrīla' (श्रील)?

---

Related:

- [What is the significance of the Titles of Spiritual Teachers?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5236/what-is-the-significance-of-the-titles-of-spiritual-teachers)
- [What's the significance of the word "Gauḍīya" in Gauḍīya Vaiṣhṇavism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/47814/whats-the-significance-of-the-word-gaud%cc%a3i%cc%84ya-in-gaud%cc%a3i%cc%84ya-vais%cc%a3hn%cc%a3avism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [अग्निरुवाच](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A9%E0%A5%AC%E0%A5%AD)
>
> लक्ष्मीवान् लक्ष्मणः **श्रीलः** स्वतन्त्रः स्वैर्य्यऽपावृतः ।
>
> > 4. **(A person endowed with fortune is denoted by the words) lakṣmīvān, lakṣmaṇa and śrīla.**
>
> Verse 4, [Chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083597.html) 367

---

##### An explanation given by the Gauḍīya ācārya - Śrīla Prabhupāda

> - Guest (1): Prabhupāda, what is the meaning of the word Śrīla?
> - Prabhupāda: Śrīla is... just like we say "Śrī" to the ordinary person. And Śrīla to very respectable person.
> - Guest (1): La.
> - Prabhupāda: La, yes. **Śrī means beauty, and la means līlā. So "one who is invested with both beauty and the power to understand the līlā
>   of Kṛṣṇa (that person is known as "*Śrīla*").**
>
> [Morning Walk - December 21, 1973, Los Angeles](https://prabhupadabooks.com/conversations/1973/dec/morning_walk/los_angeles/december/21/1973)

Comment: Excellent find!!!... I have edited the answer with links and better formatting, if you find the edit unreasonable, please revert it back. :).  Also, does any Gaudiya Acharya explains about this word in their work specifically?

Comment: @Vivikta, excellent edit. Srila Prabhupad had once given an explanation,                        Guest (1): Prabhupāda, what is the meaning of the word Śrīla?

Prabhupāda: Śrīla is... just like we say "Śrī" to the ordinary person. And Śrīla to very respectable person.

Guest (1): La.

Prabhupāda: La, yes. Śrī means beauty, and la means līlā. So "one who is invested with both beauty and the power to understand the līlā of Kṛṣṇa."            Morning Walk -- December 21, 1973, Los Angeles:

Comment: https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Prabhupada,_what_is_the_meaning_of_the_word_Srila%3F

Comment: I have edited your answer to Include Śrīla Prabhupāda's quote also, to make the answer complete. Hope you don't mind my so many transgressions on your answer. Now the answer is complete, imo. :))